# Limit apache request rate by IP

Tags: apache-2.2

Is it possible to limit each IP requesting a page from my Apache server to, say, 1 request per second?

Comment: What do you want to happen if someone tries to request two pages per second?  Do you want to send them an error page?

Comment: Preferably, their second request would wait forma second.

Comment: Make sure you're using keep-alive for this to be feasible. Browsers usually request 3-4 files until all is fetched and without keep-alive a new connection is made for each file.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a program called `tc` which pairs up with `iptables` to limit traffic.

There's another recent post asking about bandwidth limiting. The answer is the same for both of you.
[controlling the bandwidth using tc](https://serverfault.com/q/228812/64706)

Answer (score 0):

In Apache this is not done. bw_mod limit bandwidth. tc limit bandwidth. iptables connlimit limit connection. You may use iptables string and recent modules, but it is not a pretty solution.